# Can you help me with the time complexity?

Tags: time-complexity

```
int f(int n) {
    int j = n;
    while (j > 1) {
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= n * n * n * n) {
            i = 4 * i;
            print("*");
        }
        if (j / 2 > 1) {
            print(" ");
        }
        j = j / 2;
    }
    return j;
}
```

I think it is something like log2(n) * log4(n^4). How do I write it in O(n)? Is it log2 (n) * log4(n) or log2(n)^2 or something else?

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Comment: I have not checked whether your guess is right. But *O(log2(n) * log4(n^4))* = *O(logn * 4logn) = O((logn)^2)*. Notice that in big-o notation, the base of the logarithm does not matter in this case beause it can be converted to a constant term.

Answer (score 0):

The function in the question runs in `O( log(n)^2 )` time.

To clear up your confusion, as far as Big-O / asymptotic behavior goes the base of logarithms do not matter because logarithms of differing bases are related to each other by constant factors (by the definition of logarithms) and constant factors do not affect Big-O.

In this case the inner loop is

```
int i = 1;
while (i <= n * n * n * n) {
    i = 4 * i;
}
```

which will terminate when `4^i <= n^4`. If we take the log of both sides of that inequality, by any base, we get `i log(4) <= 4 log(n)` so `i` grows like `(4/log(4)) log(n)`. Since `4/log(4)` is a constant we see that `i` grows like `log(n)`, or is `O(log(n))`.

Likewise the outer loop

```
int j = n;
while (j > 1) {
   //...
   j = j / 2;
}
```

runs as many time as you can divide `n` by 2 which is O(log(n)).

So we have a `O(log(n))` inner loop that will run `O(log(n))` times which means the whole running time is `O(log(n)^2)`.